# Can I define a gdb command that works with pointer or object?

Tags: gdb, user-defined, gdb-python

Suppose I create a gdb user-defined command like this:

```
define pfoo
call foo_printer($arg0)
end
```

where `foo_printer` takes a pointer argument.  Then if I have a pointer variable `pf` I can do:

```
pfoo pf
```

But if I have a non-pointer variable `f`, I need to remember to provide `&`:

```
pfoo &f
```

Is there a way to define the command to work with either pointer or non-pointer argument?  Ie, so both of these would work:

```
pfoo pf
pfoo f
```

Comment: I don't think this is implementable with GDB scripting, but it is trivial to implement using embedded Python support.

Answer (score 0):

As a novice to the GDB Python API, this is what I came up with:

```
class FooPrinter (gdb.Command):
    """Print a FOO (pointer or not, may be nil)"""
    def __init__(self):
        super(FooPrinter, self).__init__("pfoo", gdb.COMMAND_USER)
    def invoke(self, foo, from_tty):
        gdb_foo = gdb.parse_and_eval(foo)
        if gdb_foo.type.code == gdb.TYPE_CODE_PTR:
            if not gdb_foo.address:
                gdb.write("<nil>\n")
            else:
                gdb.execute("call foo_printer(" + foo + ")")
        else:
            gdb.execute("call foo_printer(&" + foo + ")")

FooPrinter()
```

(And then source that file in `.gdbinit`.)

Please do let me know if this might be improved.